# How does WordPress determine the primary plugin PHP file?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

*(Background: I'm trying to automate the setup of some WP blogs by writing directly to the `active_plugins` row in `wp_options`, and I'm having an issue in determining the primary PHP file for some plugins.)*

The main PHP file for most plugins is simply the name of the stub, with `.php` appended; for example, `plugin-name/plugin-name.php`.

However that's not the case for all plugins. [WP Super Cache](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/) for example has the following structure:

```
wp-super-cache
├── Changelog.txt
├── advanced-cache.php
├── languages
├── ossdl-cdn.php
├── plugins
├── readme.txt
├── wp-cache-base.php
├── wp-cache-config-sample.php
├── wp-cache-phase1.php
├── wp-cache-phase2.php
├── wp-cache.php
└── wp-super-cache.pot
```

If you go look in the Plugin admin panel, this plugin can be activated with the following link:

```
'http://localhost/testing/wp-admin/plugins.php?action=activate&plugin=wp-super-cache%2Fwp-cache.php&plugin_status=all&paged=1&s&_wpnonce=cbc0e620a3'

/* Note how WP has determined: plugin=wp-super-cache/wp-cache.php */
```

**My question is, how does WP determine which PHP file in a plugin directory is the main PHP file?**

Or in other words, if I wanted to manually update the `active_plugins` `option_value` in the `wp_options` table, how would I know what PHP file to reference?

I've tried to figure this out by digging through the code, but it's very convoluted and I'm getting lost. I thought WP might look at the first X lines of every file to find the one with the banner info (Author, Plugin Name etc...) but that seems very awkward.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no "main" file to a plugin. Every file that has the plugin header is a plugin and the rest are not. Convention is that there is only one file with the header in a directory, but I saw "plugins" that had more than one such file in a directory, and they appeared as multiple plugins in the admin, but that was long time ago, don't think anybody does it now.

Comment: What I'm trying to understand then is how WP determines the PHP file that it will pass by the `plugin` GET parameter when you activate a plugin from the admin panel (see second code snippet in my post). You can hover over the `Activate` link in the Plugin panel to see it on your WP setup. This is the same PHP file that gets inserted into the `active_plugins` option in the `wp_options` DB table... I'm just calling it "Primary" for lack of better term.

Comment: on the plugin admin page it scans all the subdirectories under the plugins directory and reads the header info.from the php files. the `get_plugins`  function does it https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_plugins/

Comment: I always set only one plugin file with the header.

Comment: To look for the actual plugin files in a particular plugin folder, the `get_plugins()` function needs the name of the folder starting with `/`. So, for example, to get the actual plugin filename and info for "Akismet Anti-Spam", call `get_plugins("/akismet")`. The leading "`/`" is counterintuitive!